# Change value in variable when dragging an item AngularJS JQuery-UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have three divs:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  countries and cities
  <ul class="source">
    <li data-value="country">USA</li>
    <li data-value="country">France</li>
    <li class="city" data-value="city">Paris</li>
    <li data-value="city">Rome</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div id="divCountries" class="col-sm-4">
  Countries
  <ul id="countries">
  </ul>
</div>


<div id="divCities" class="col-sm-4">
  Cities
  <ul id="cities">
    <li class="city" data-value="city">London</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I drag one of the cities to the div with id="divCities", I want a variable to turn true.

Here you have a plunker that's kind of close to what I want.

https://plnkr.co/edit/XOVRgqxOyVNPnKawQ8pA?p=preview

If I add a priori 2 cities inside the div with id="divCities" the variable will be true and then the answer will be correct. But if I have one and drag the second into there it does not turn true.

As the plunker is now, you can see there's one city with class="city" inside #divCities.
When I drag Paris, which has class="city", into the div with id="divCities" the count of elements with class="city" should be 2 and the following variable should turn true.

```
   $scope.exercise = $('#divCities .city').length === 2;
```

and then if it is true it should activate a ng-show and display "correct".

What am I missing? Any help please?

Thank you :)

Comment: Use drag event https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code just add a drag event which triggers on dragging, in that event handler change your variable to true

Here is the code

```
$(".source li").draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  drag:function(){
    console.log('do things here which works on drag');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :)
I also came up with another solution. I moved the $scope.exercise = $('#divCities .city').length === 2; inside the function so it only counts when the user clicks on the button